# How can I solve the reportMissingModuleSource by using Django and docker-compose without creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, virtual-environment

I've tried to create a new project with Django and docker-compose without creating virtual environment.
But now, when I want to start coding in VS Code, I get the reportMissingModuleSource.
For example in mysite/urls.py "Import "django.contrib" could not be resolved from sourcePylance"

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl shift P, select the right interpreter go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).